# Sequence with fractional second intervals in R

Tags: r, time, sequence

How would I create a continuous sequence with an interval in fractional seconds in R?

For example, I need jumps of 0.03125 seconds.

Am I on the right track with this?:

```
seq(from=as.POSIXct("14:03:55","%H-%M-%S",tz="UTC"),
to=as.POSIXct("19:30:07", "%H-%M-%S", tz="UTC"),
by="seconds",
length=0.0315)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format argument to `as.POSIXct` needs to have colons instead of hyphens to match the format of the time values. `by` should be the interval between values in the sequence. `length.out` can be used to specify the total number of values you want in the sequence, rather than specifying the interval with `by`.

```
options(digits.secs=4) 

time.seq = seq(from=as.POSIXct("14:03:55", format="%H:%M:%OS",tz="UTC"),    
    to=as.POSIXct("19:30:07", format="%H:%M:%OS", tz="UTC"), by=0.0315)

head(time.seq)
[1] "2016-01-21 14:03:55.0000 UTC" "2016-01-21 14:03:55.0315 UTC"
[3] "2016-01-21 14:03:55.0629 UTC" "2016-01-21 14:03:55.0945 UTC"
[5] "2016-01-21 14:03:55.1259 UTC" "2016-01-21 14:03:55.1575 UTC"
```

Note that since there's no date given, `as.POSIXct` attaches today's date to the time values.

Comment: Thank you! This was incredibly helpful