# R rounding issue on fractional seconds

Tags: r, time, sequence

I'm trying to create a sequence for a timeseries sampled at a frequency of 10Hz (i.e. a period of 0.1 secs)

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34927600/sequence-with-fractional-second-intervals-in-r) I used:

```
> options(digits.secs=4)
```

then:

```
> time.seq = seq(from=as.POSIXlt("00:00:00.0", format="%H:%M:%OS",tz="GMT"),                   length.out=10, by=0.10)
```

which returns:

```
> head(time.seq)
[1] "2018-02-08 00:00:00.0 GMT" "2018-02-08 00:00:00.0 GMT"
[3] "2018-02-08 00:00:00.2 GMT" "2018-02-08 00:00:00.2 GMT"
[5] "2018-02-08 00:00:00.4 GMT" "2018-02-08 00:00:00.5 GMT"
```

This isn't right. [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726034/how-r-formats-posixct-with-fractional-seconds) should be:

```
"2018-02-08 00:00:00.1 GMT"
```

and [4]

```
"2018-02-08 00:00:00.3 GMT"
```

Initially I thought that the problem was with formatting or getOption but that doesn't seem to be the case since if I use a different fraction, it works perfectly:

```
> time.seq = seq(from=as.POSIXlt("00:00:00.0", format="%H:%M:%OS",tz="GMT"),                   length.out=10, by=0.0315)
> head(time.seq)
[1] "2018-02-08 00:00:00.0000 GMT" "2018-02-08 00:00:00.0315 GMT"
[3] "2018-02-08 00:00:00.0629 GMT" "2018-02-08 00:00:00.0945 GMT"
[5] "2018-02-08 00:00:00.1259 GMT" "2018-02-08 00:00:00.1575 GMT"
```

So this implies that there is some rounding error.

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this, please? I'm using R 3.4.1 on OS X (High Sierra)

Thanks!

UPDATE
From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726034/how-r-formats-posixct-with-fractional-seconds) I can see that there this is a floating point error in the addition. Using the 'form' formatting function in that post from Matthew Lundberg I get:

```
f4 <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS4"
> time.seq = seq(from=as.POSIXlt("00:00:00.0", format="%H:%M:%OS",tz="GMT"),                   length.out=10, by=0.10)
> format(time.seq[1], f4)
[1] "2018-02-09 00:00:00.0000"
> format(time.seq[2], f4)
[1] "2018-02-09 00:00:00.0999"
> format(time.seq[3], f4)
[1] "2018-02-09 00:00:00.2000"
```

This presumably means that for some reason the formatting in R isn't picking up my option setting:

```
> options(digits.secs=4)
```

Comment: Computers aren't as good at adding decimals as you think they are. The problem is basically the same as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed an inconsistency between

- `format.POSIXlt` (which is also called by `print.POSIXlt`) determining the number of **necessary relevant digits** (considering `getOption("digits.secs")` as the *max*, but in your case relevant digits would be just 1 since .099999 rounded to 4 digits is still .1000)
- the **internal** code called by `format.POSIXlt` as `.Internal(format.POSIXlt(x, format, usetz))`, which probably just cuts (or floors?) to the determined number of relevant digits, without actually rounding the same way

---

**Edit:**
Having had time to look at the linked post [how-r-formats-posixct-with-fractional-seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726034/how-r-formats-posixct-with-fractional-seconds), I guess everything else has been said / discussed there, in particular, that rounding up could be more involved if you reach 60 seconds, which might be the main reason why things are as they are.